# Combo Box "showReadonlyAsDisabled" Property Not Working

Tags: xpages

I have a combo box on my XPage with showReadonlyAsDisabled marked true:

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="ComboTest"
    defaultValue="One"
    showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"
    readonly="true">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="One"
        itemValue="One">
    </xp:selectItem>
</xp:comboBox>
```

However, the combo box still displays as read-only (text) and not as the disabled control. Is this a bug? The showReadonlyAsDisabled property appears to work on other controls (input, radio, etc.). I'm using Designer 9.0.1FP4 and the Domino server is on 9.0.1FP5.

EDIT (showing combo box with data binding):

**Comobo box in custom control**

```
<xp:comboBox
    id="Address"
    value="#{Location.AddressType}"
    defaultValue="Street Address"
    showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"
    readonly="true">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:keywords.getSelectItem("Address Type", true);}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

**Data binding on parent XPage**

```
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="Location"
        formName="Location"
        action="editDocument"
        documentId="#{javascript:param.location}">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
```

Comment: Your example has no data binding to its `value` property, so it seems to be be editable. Try binding it to a Document's Item/Field and setting that Document's `action` to open document (instead of create or edit), you should see it behave as expected.

Comment: It still doesn't work as expected when I have data binding on the value.

Comment: It's a feature I use surprisingly regularly. Could you expand your example to give a completed picture of it being bound?

Comment: Sure. I edited my question. Also, the other controls do not appear to need data binding for the showReadonlyAsDisabled to work which is odd. I also tried setting the Document's action to open which did not work either.

Comment: @EricMcCormick - I'm assuming this property is working for you on combo boxes then? What version of Designer / Domino are you running?

Comment: I have to take back what I said. I use `showReadonlyAsDisabled` plenty of places, but wasn't able to find an example w/ an _xp:radioGroup_. I tried created an example (similar to yours above), but found that it still renders the read only version of it. This seems familiar, like I heard someone else mention this in recent history. For ref: I'm on Domino 9.0.1 FP5.

Comment: If you're in the [XPages Slack chat](https://xpages-slack.herokuapp.com/), there was some talk of this ~Feb 23rd in the beginners chat. Paul Withers recommended a Dojo Radio Button, as this is apparently a known bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with all kinds of selection controls that are rendered as html tables in read mode (which in my opinion is even more annoying than just this "show disabled in read mode" bug as it makes styling unnecessarily complicated). This however is only happening if the control is bound to a document datasource.

So what you can try is create a second combo box on you page and bind it to a viewScope variable, then make sure the correct value is copied over from the Notes field upon page load, then make sure only one insstance of tyour control is visible in read / edit mode:

For a datasource named `Location`, and a Notes field `AddressType` this would be in `beforePageLoad`:

```
if(!doc1.isNewNote()){
    viewScope.comboField=Location.getItemValueString("AddressType");
}
```

This would be the markup for your original / editable comboBox control:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" value="#{Location.AddressType}" rendered="#{javascript:doc1.isEditable()}" defaultValue="Street Address">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:keywords.getSelectItem("Address Type", true);}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

This would be the markup for your additional / disabled comboBox control:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox2" value="#{viewScope.AddressType}" disabled="true" rendered="#{javascript:!doc1.isEditable()}">
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:keywords.getSelectItem("Address Type", true);}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following XML part to the `faces-config.xml` of your application.

With this, the renderer for the ComboBox will be set to the default, not read-only renderer. Then, your ComboBox should appear as you want.

```
<renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Menu.ReadOnly</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```